# Searching DateTimePicker component with calendar weeks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm searching for a component. I need a DateTimePicker which is capable of displaying the calendar week. I have found various DatePicker's which support this feature but no DateTimePicker.
Is there a component like this? I was not able to finde one.

My problem is, that I can't use two separate fields (a DatePicker and a TimePicker) because it need's to be one field with one name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited my answer completely to reflect the actual solution:

Found a DateTimePicker based on the twitter bootstrap. There is an option to show calendar weeks that you could try.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#calendarweeks

Comment: Looks good, but where is the option for the calendar week? That's the only thing I need. Everything else works perfect.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: "calendar week" might be the wrong word. I want to display the number of the week besides in my picker like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/vhCalendar/main.jpg). It's just a random pick from google but you get the idea.

Comment: I found one that's in VB.Net or C#. It's probably not what you're looking for though. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17063/ExtendedDateTimePicker-control-with-week-numbers

Comment: Hm no, not really. But you helped me, so I accept your answer :)

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much! I'm not familiar with GitHub, I haven't found the docs for the component. I used the "calendarWeeks" property and it worked! The doc refers to V4 Beta, but it also worked with master. THANKS! 
Mind adding this to your answer? Not as an Edit, as solution? THAnKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered:

```html
<input type="week" name="week_year" />
<input type="time" name="time"/>
<br>
<input type="datetime-local" name="datetimepicker" placeholder="datetime"/>
```

Comment: The question's constraints require a single field to access the date/time.